# cannot set/read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

This is basically two errors but they go hand in hand since the second error goes back to the first one

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Players' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CreatePlayer' of undefined

```
var TotalPlayers = 0;
Player.Players = [];

Player.CreatePlayer = function (name, Class, rank) {
    TotalPlayers ++;
    Player.Players[TotalPlayers] = {
        name: name,
        Class: Class,
        rank: rank
    };
    Player[name] = new Player(name, Class, rank);
};
```

There is more to the code than this but this should be the only
parts needed

Comment: how you define `Player`?

Comment: the player object is defined view full code here:http://exitium.esy.es/project/entity.js

Comment: the moment when need use `function Player(){...}` instead `var Player=function(){...}` :-)

Comment: well if you just declare it as a function wouldn't that make it a function instead of object

Comment: try see [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you declaring what `Player` is? With the code you're presenting, you're missing its initialization:

```
var Player = {
    Players: []
};
var TotalPlayers = 0;
```

---

I just read the code you posted, `Player` is defined *after* using it for the first time, so at the very least you should move the following to the top:

```
var Player = function(name, Class) {
    // ...
};
```

Another option would be to *declare* it using the function statement:

```
function Player(name, Class) { ... };
```

This will give you the same result and since in javascript functions are evaluated first, the name will always be available. You may benefit from reading more about [Function Declarations vs. Function Expressions](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `var Player = {}` after (or before) `var TotalPlayers = 0;`

in addition instead of counting the total players you can simply push them to the array:

```
Player.Players.push({
        name: name,
        Class: Class,
        rank: rank
    });
```